# Poltergeist haunt (#17) - do item tokens count for the poltergeist's damage track?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In the poltergeist haunt, heroes are collecting item tokens (candles) to defeat the poltergeist. The Poltergeist wants to accumulate items to get stronger (move the damage track).

In our game, a hero died who was carrying two candles. I was the traitor. I had my poltergeist pick up the dropped candles and thought I should move the track forward but there was some disagreement since the candle item tokens weren't item *cards*.

In the rulebook it pretty clearly says that item tokens should be treated as any other item. Should I have moved the damage track forward for each item I picked up from dead heroes?

Comment: Can you confirm which edition and which haunt number this is for?  The links [[1](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_SurvivalRev_120105.pdf)][[2](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf)] to the rules on the wizards website do not match your description.  Searching the document for "candles" or "poltergeist" don't reveal anything either.  Often times such situations are explicitly stated in the haunting scenario itself as being allowed or not such as "the poltergeist cannot pick up candles" etc but without access to the rules I cannot confirm either way.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, the candles should be treated as items.

At no point does the haunt specify item **cards**. **Item** tokens and **item** cards are all items, as are most omens. As you pointed out, the rulebook clarifies that item tokens are just like other items, except when the haunt specifies otherwise.